# Change layout at autorotation

Tags: android, layout, screen-rotation

I want to make a picture gallery with a vertical layout with two parts: image on
top, and horizontally scrollable icons below. I know how to do this.

But I also want that, when autorotated, icons stay on the right. That is, I want
to change the vertical layout by a horizontal one, and horizontal
scrollbar by a vertical one.

How to do this? Any clues/links would be appreciated.

Thanks!

L.

Comment: that sounds trivial. what have you tried ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want different layouts for each orientation (landscape, portait) and possibly more for different screen sizes. Start with the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).

If you have specific issues, post the issue(s), some code for what you have tried and we'll see if we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

you must have multiple layouts. create 2 layouts. one in `layout` folder for portrait and copy it and paste it in `layout-land` folder for landscape then customize each other.

Comment: MMmm... I see. So instead of changing layouts (that I tried to do), to have multiple ones, and use the corresponding one for each orientation..... Makes sense. I'll try that. Thanks!